# Google Cloud Java (No Class Def)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

I am having issues when trying to use:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(is))
                    .build()
                    .getService();
```

in Google Cloud Storage. It says that:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/threeten/bp/Duration;
```

On my gradle, I have the following code:

```
compile (
            [group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: '1.3.3'],
            [group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '1.2.1']
    )
    compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-appengine'
    }
```

I am not sure how to incorporate it into the build. I am currently running Android Lollipop.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you change the gradle line to `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud:0.20.1-alpha'`?

Comment: Yes I do get the same problem.